# How onFling works in viewSwitcher

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair, onfling, viewswitcher

I have 2 layouts inside a viewSwitcher, I need to change when I swipe that.

```
package slide.trys.one;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class SlideActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

private ViewSwitcher switcher;
private GestureDetector gesturedetector = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gesturedetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}


int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 100;
int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) {

    float ev1X = e1.getX();
    float ev2X = e2.getX();

    final float xdistance = Math.abs(ev1X - ev2X);

    final float xvelocity = Math.abs(velocityX);

    if( (xvelocity > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) && (xdistance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) )
    {
        if(ev1X > ev2X)
        {
            switcher.showNext(); //Error in this part
        }
        else
        {
            switcher.showPrevious(); //Error in this part
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,float distanceY) {
    return false;
}

public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

}
```

I'm a newbie for java and Android too. pls help me, where am I doing mistake ?
I getting error with `switcher.showNext()` and `switcher.showPrevious()` .

pls help. the example I have is using android 4.0.3, But I need to work on 2.1. I don't know how to fix this.

Will the viewSwitcher works on Android 2.1 ??

my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/in_animation"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/out_animation" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/footer" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/blue_header" />

    </RelativeLayout>        

    </ViewSwitcher>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You must post your layout here in order someone to find your error, maybe it's in xml

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewFlipper better for switching between layouts.

First of all, understand the difference between ViewFlipper and ViewSwitcher.
Also, for 2.1, in the case of ViewFlipper, there is a bug present(up to Android 2.3.4), the workaround is here:

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2010/05/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered.html

So, you extend ViewFlipper and do the workaround for the bug, and in xml you access your CustomViewFlipper like that:

```
<com.mypackage.MyViewFlipper
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/news_layout_flipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_to_show">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_to_show">
    </LinearLayout>
</com.mypackage.MyViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I did nothing, but it worked now. But I'm facing another issue. This swipe works fine when I'm using it separately. but when I implement it inside the scrollView then it doesn't work, any help ?

Comment: This is because scrollView does Gesture detection by itself. It will not work as you expect. Don't do this, revise your architecture or what you want to do. Normally, you can put a layer above the scrollview and  detect swipe on it and decide to pass it or not to scroll view.

Comment: Can you pls explain a little more. coz, I'm newbie. So.
what do you mean by layer above scrollView ?